# Prevent image flicker when setting img src object url in async pipe

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have a JWT authorized endpoint for images, so we can't directly link to image urls in html.

The workaround is to have this async pipe that loads the image with correct authorization (via http interceptor, not shown), and sets the img.src attribute to an "object" url.

HTML:

```html
<img [attr.src]="environment.apiUrl + 'users/image/' + userId | secureImage | async" alt="Avatar" />
```

Pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Pipe({
    name: 'secureImage'
})
export class SecureImagePipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

    transform(url): Observable<SafeUrl> {
        return this.http
            .get(url, { responseType: 'blob' })
            .pipe(map(val => this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(val))));
    }
}
```

As you can see in this GIF, when the image changes from the plus sign (static), to the homer brain (loaded via this pipe), there is a very short flicker where it shows the classic "image not found" along with the alt text (Avatar).

[Flicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbxkO.gif)

How can I prevent this flickering?

UPDATE: Removing the "alt" attributes removes the "broken image" image, which looks much better.

So from this:

```html
<img [attr.src]="environment.apiUrl + 'users/image/' + userId | secureImage | async" alt="Avatar" />
```

to this:

```html
<img [attr.src]="environment.apiUrl + 'users/image/' + userId | secureImage | async" />
```

I'm keeping this question open as there may be people that must have the alt attribute, so my solution wouldn't work for them.

Comment: because when new image src is applied at that time new image is not loaded fully.. so you have to set path to src of image only when there is loaded image from async pipe...

Answer (score 0):

When you click the button and load the image, there is a short time frame in which the image is not fully loaded from the server and the < img > will display the alt text.

To prevent this, download the image from the server through a component/service and only set the src once the image is fully done loading.

Comment: I tried to await the promise and the image is actually fully loaded before I set the src, but the flicker was still there. I found a solution that I'm happy with though, by removing the alt-tag (see updated description).

Comment: @Pikabanga Your image tags should provide an alt text to display when the image cannot be loaded (Either through a server error or slow connections).
Its hard to know where the issue is without more code, the underlying issue should still be the same, but I cant be sure unless you provide more information on how you got the image through a promise and when you set the src.